# How to test menu in Android?

Tags: android, robolectric

I need to write tests to menu in Android application using Robolectric.

Source code of menu:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        tokenProvider.destroyToken(this);
        tokenProvider.destroyEmail(this);
        Intent nextActivity = new intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(nextActivity);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Please help to write tests

Comment: You're asking too broad question without providing enough of context. Do you have any Robolectric infrastructure? What are the component names? Did you try anything yourself already and have an error message? Please read this first https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1):

You can test Menu using robolectric by creating `MenuItem` with `RoboMenuItem` and passing that menuItem to activity's `onOptionsItemSelected()`.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class , sdk = 21)
public class AboutTheAppFragmentTest {

private Context context;
private YourActivity activity;
private ActivityController<YourActivity> controller;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    context = RuntimeEnvironment.application.getApplicationContext();
    controller = Robolectric.buildActivity(YourActivity.class);

    activity = controller
            .create()
            .start()
            .resume()
            .visible()
            .get();
}

@Test
public void testMenuOptionsSelected(){
    MenuItem menuItem = new RoboMenuItem(R.id.your_menu_id);
    activity.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
    //write your test assertion
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    controller.pause().stop().destroy();
    controller = null;
    context = null;
}
```

}